# Removing part of a string with data.table

Tags: r

I have a data table that has some strings, where I find repeated stuff I just need for identification of certain lines. I first want to identify certain rows with it (and create a new variable based on it. Than I want to strip that part (x) in my example) away.

I know there are solutions, that don't use data.table.
However, the question is for me to learn data.table better and I need the enhanced time performance of %chin% which is why I like to learn to set it up in a data.table way.

```
c <- c("a", "b (x)", "c", "d (x)")
d <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

c_name <- "string"
d_name <- "numeric"

df <- data.frame(c,d)
names(df) <- c(c_name,d_name)
setDT(df)

#Now comes the part where I want to create a new variable "Newvar" that only has text, if no "(x)" is in (%chin%) the string variable c:
df[ !( c %chin% c("(x)")) , Newvar:="had (x)"]
#My code does not work. It just takes All Rows. 

#Next I want to remove all parts with (x) in string var c:
df[ ( c %chin% c("(x)")) , c ]
#this does not work like this.
```

I don't get any error messages, but my final data set should look like this:

```
#Final data set generation:

# 1) manually searching for (x)
Newvar <- c("", "had (x)","", "had (x)" )
# 2) "renaming" the string variable c
df$string <- gsub("\\(x\\)*", "", df$string)

#so actually the solution should be:
  df$string <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

However in my real-problem, I cannot code anything by hand in a life-time :D

Comment: Nicely reproducible example, but don't post code like `rm(list = ls())` on stack overflow. I would hate to copy/paste code from your question and accidentally run that line.

Comment: Oh sorry, I will remove that! I am so sorry, I have not known!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%chin%` does exact matching of full strings, just like `%in%`, but faster. You are trying to use it like for partial matching within strings. To match patterns *within* a string, use `grep` (or `grepl`, which returns a `logical`, which is good for this case).

```
c
# [1] "a"     "b (x)" "c"     "d (x)"
c %chin% "(x)"
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
grepl("(x)", c, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

If you switch to using `grepl`, I think your code will work as you expect. I use `fixed = TRUE` because we are matching an exact pattern, not a regular expression.

I also find it strange that you go out of your way to name the `c` column `"string"`, but you always use `c`, the vector, rather than `df$string`, the column in the `data.table`. I would recommend modifying to

```
# old
df[ !( c %chin% c("(x)")) , Newvar:="had (x)"]
# new: use `grepl` instead of `%chin%`, and `string` instead of `c`
df[ !grepl("(x)", string, fixed = TRUE) , Newvar:="had (x)"]
```

Comment: Dear Gregor, Thank you. I have no clue why I use c later instead of string, I introduced it for clarity but did not do it completely. And obviously the neglect (!) also is misused, because I obviously want those that have the term "(x)". What exacly does fixed do? From the help it is "logical. If TRUE, pattern is a string to be matched as is. Overrides all conflicting arguments." But what does it mean?

Comment: `grepl`, by default, uses regex. Regex is a powerful way to match patterns, with lots of special characters, including parentheses. You do not need regex here, `fixed = TRUE` disables regex, saying you want to match a fixed substring, not a pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Gregor!